# Is "folder/".htmlentities($_GET["location"]).".filetype" safe?

Tags: php

I am trying to validate a form by finding out if I have a picture of the user's requested item, so I need to ensure I keep within the images folder when checking if images/*item*.jpg exists. Is there any way a user could go backwards from the images directory and pick an invalid item or would this be OK for validating my form?

```
<?php if(file_exists("images/".htmlentities($_GET["location"]).".jpg"): ?>
```

There are no directories in the images folder so I don't have to worry about them using "/" in their item name.

Comment: Have you tried setting $_GET['location'] to something like `../index.php`?

Comment: I don't see why this was marked as a duplicate for one that specifies not using realpath(). Couldn't I just use realpath() instead of file_exists() to solve my problem?!

Comment: @TomHart If I manually change it to <?php if(file_exists("images/".htmlentities("../index.php\0").".jpg"): ?> that doesn't return true even though there is an index.php outside of my images directory. **Edit** I now notice that this is because htmlentities stops when it hits the \0, meaning it is looking for images/../index.php.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**. As far as I can remember, `htmlentities()` doesn't escape the null-byte `\0`, the dot `.`, the slash `/` and the backslash `\`.

The null-byte truncates your path/file name. And the dot makes for relative path traversing (`.` = current directory, `..` = parent directory, `\` (Windows) and `/` = root directory).

Now, consider your inserted variable to be `../config.php\0` and be afraid if you were planning even serving that 'image'.

Comment: More generally, `htmlentities` is used to protect against XSS when you insert a string into an HTML document, not when you use a string as a file system path.

Comment: I tried injecting the null byte and it gets stripped when it is reached in htmlentities, but I can hop in and out of folders with `../` and `/`. Thanks, I'll edit my code to strip out `.` and `/` and `\ ` and return false if any of them are present.

Answer (score 0):

NO,You should always use in pics/hosted files folder .htaccses to prevent direct ACCSES :

i would add this :

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|php3|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|php|exe|asp|aspx|zip|html|js|htm|htpasswd|inc|bak|bmp)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And also i would suggest you to using HTMLPURIFIER either is much safer:

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

With purifier it will look like :

```
<?php if(file_exists("images/".$purifier->purify($_GET["location"]).".jpg"): ?>
```

Comment: Telling the server to deny access to the browser won't stop PHP from accessing it. Converting text to HTML for use inside a directory path is nonsense.

Comment: @Quentin WHAT are you talking about ???????? "HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it will also make sure your documents are standards compliant" HTMLPURIFIER is for remove malicious code not only convert from to "TEXT TO HTML" LOL! Every big sites using it.if i could i would downvote your comment. And also htaccses doing what he should do.

Comment: It's for removing code that is malicious in an HTML document, which this isn't.

Comment: LOL! it's for everything not just HTML document.(PHP)

Comment: No, it really, really isn't. That is why it is called **HTML** Purifier and not  Any Kind Of Code Purifier.

Comment: I am not sure you know what is HTMLPURIFIER or what is for,go do some homeworks,good luck.

Comment: I know exactly what HTML Purifier is and does. It is a useful product when you want to accept HTML as user input and then republish it. It isn't useful for testing if a file name is sensible.

Comment: Also let's see what you'r answer ,i am curios how to clean malcious code from GETS. -.-

Comment: There is already a good answer in the duplicate question. (And where the potentially malicious code comes from doesn't matter, it is where you put it that counts).